# No house wrap on 2007 built southern Oregon house, insurance claim or something that should be warrantied?

Tags: house-wrap, remodel, warranty

I am installing a second story deck. I cut into the T1-11 to get at the rim joist. There is no house wrap under the T1-11, but there is 1/2 inch osb sheathing. I also cut through the sheathing, and they're is no house wrap under that, just the rim joist.

There isn't house wrap or any variation of house wrap (felt etc...)

Should this be something I try to get warrantied or put an insurance claim in for?

Comment: 16 years seems a long time for a warranty claim, and I doubt (but could be wrong) that insurance would do much *unless* you showed this was a cause of actual damages.

Comment: That's quite a few code cycles ago as well. Got any evidence that it was a required or mandated detail **at that time in that place?** Even if it was, you're highly unlikely to get anyone to pay to fix it now other than you, should you choose to. Could be they met a code requirement by taping the joints of the T111, as another possible thing to consider.

Comment: Is the T1-11 primed on the back side?

Comment: @JimStewart, no, it isn't. I'm doing my best to flash under it as is.

Comment: Is it a "best practice" to backprime T1-11? A really competent paint store proprietor in warm, wet New Iberia LA told me that an old practice in south Louisiana was to back prime fascia boards and this would give fascia boards an indefinite service life. He said some ante-bellum homes had original fascia boards because of this. Does anybody backprime T1-11?